# Displaying correct storage space using Samba (multiple hard disks)

Tags: networking, mount, hard-drive, samba, file-sharing

I have created a shared folder using Samba that I access from a Windows computer. Just recently though I mounted a new drive to a folder inside the shared one, to "unify" the disks to one. There are probably a million reasons why I shouldn't have done this, and I would actually consider **ANY** better way to achieve this (sharing both disks on a single network point), so... My problem right now lies in the shown storage space, since from my laptop I can only see the main disk space, rather then the sum of the two. When I move files in the mounted folder the remaining space simply doesn't change... Once again I'm totally open to alternatives!
Sorry if it's a rookie question, but I'm new to both the OS (Ubuntu 20.04.4 btw) and the network sharing.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: To confirm, the problem is that your Windows notebook is not reporting the total amount of storage space on the Samba server correctly? Does Ubuntu itself report the correct size of the storage devices? 

Comment: Exactly, Windows shows the main drive's capacity, where the shared folder is located, and to an inner folder I've mounted a second drive. Ubuntu shows that both drives are present. The "problem" probably lies within Samba's code, that's why I asked about any good alternative.